# Linux perf test on 3.10 kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, performance-testing, perf

I am trying perf test on imx6dl arm target, 2 subtests are failing on perf and are:

1. perf test -v 15

15: Test breakpoint overflow signal handler                :

```
--- start ---

count1 0, count2 0, overflow 0

failed: wrong count for bp10

failed: wrong overflow hit

failed: wrong count for bp2

---- end ----

Test breakpoint overflow signal handler: FAILED!
```

2. perf test -v 16

16: Test breakpoint overflow sampling                      :

```
--- start ---

    count 0, overflow 0

    Wrong number of executions 0 != 10000

    Wrong number of overflows 0 != 100

---- end ----

Test breakpoint overflow sampling: FAILED!
```

Please help me out why all the values are showing zero.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your  imx6dl arm may have no hardware performance counters or no interrupt-on-overflow mode on them. Or your kernel has no support of such hardware. You should check exact core name and configuration of your chip and ARM's documentation on hardware performance counters implemented in it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution posted.                                                  However I tried with dmesg logs and found taht                                    hw perfevents: enabled with ARMv7 Cortex-A9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
==================> perf_pmu_register pmu->name = ARMv7 Cortex-A9
CPU PMU: attempt to register multiple PMU devices!
arm-pmu: probe of arm-pmu failed with error -28            . How do i detect no interrupt-on-overflow mode ?